# go/k8s: controller-runtime upgrade, fake client lacks functionality

Tags: unit-testing, go, kubernetes

I am attempting to upgrade `controller-runtime` from version 0.13.0 to 0.16.3, which has introduced several issues with tests due to breaking changes.

I have managed to resolve most of them, but there is one specific use case that I cannot address.

The code creates a custom resource and then updates its status. While everything works as expected, the problem arises in the test phase. The test utilizes the fake client from the `client/fake` package.

The issue lies in the fact that when a new custom resource (CR) object is created in the fake client's memory, it appears that a corresponding object is not generated under `fakeSubResourceClient` for status updates. Consequently, this leads to a "not found error," which should not occur and only happens in tests, not in production.

I have attempted to seek assistance from various AI bots and have also searched for similar use cases in public GitHub repositories, but with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Indeed this is not something that supported according to the links below 

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/issues/2362#issuecomment-1699415588

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/issues/2386#issuecomment-1607768830

I will try to make some workaround and update

Answer (score 1):

OK so after verifying that indeed the fake client doesn't support this scenario, I came up with a workaround that works pretty well, here's the code

```
type ErrorInjectingFakeClient struct {
    client.WithWatch
    withSubResourceSimulation bool
    withObjects               []client.Object
    withStatusSubresource     []client.Object
    failError                 error
}

func NewErrorInjectingFakeClient(scheme *runtime.Scheme, withSubResourceSimulation bool, initObjects ...client.Object) *ErrorInjectingFakeClient {
    builder := fake.NewClientBuilder().
        WithScheme(scheme).
        WithObjects(initObjects...).
        WithStatusSubresource(initObjects...)
    return &ErrorInjectingFakeClient{
        withSubResourceSimulation: withSubResourceSimulation,
        WithWatch:                 builder.Build(),
        withObjects:               initObjects,
        withStatusSubresource:     initObjects,
    }
}

// Copied from sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.3/pkg/client/fake/client.go#1217
var inTreeResourcesWithStatus = []schema.GroupVersionKind{
    {Version: "v1", Kind: "Namespace"},
    {Version: "v1", Kind: "Node"},
    {Version: "v1", Kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"},
    {Version: "v1", Kind: "PersistentVolume"},
    {Version: "v1", Kind: "Pod"},
    {Version: "v1", Kind: "ReplicationController"},
    {Version: "v1", Kind: "Service"},

    {Group: "apps", Version: "v1", Kind: "Deployment"},
    {Group: "apps", Version: "v1", Kind: "DaemonSet"},
    {Group: "apps", Version: "v1", Kind: "ReplicaSet"},
    {Group: "apps", Version: "v1", Kind: "StatefulSet"},

    {Group: "autoscaling", Version: "v1", Kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"},

    {Group: "batch", Version: "v1", Kind: "CronJob"},
    {Group: "batch", Version: "v1", Kind: "Job"},

    {Group: "certificates.k8s.io", Version: "v1", Kind: "CertificateSigningRequest"},

    {Group: "networking.k8s.io", Version: "v1", Kind: "Ingress"},
    {Group: "networking.k8s.io", Version: "v1", Kind: "NetworkPolicy"},

    {Group: "policy", Version: "v1", Kind: "PodDisruptionBudget"},

    {Group: "storage.k8s.io", Version: "v1", Kind: "VolumeAttachment"},

    {Group: "apiextensions.k8s.io", Version: "v1", Kind: "CustomResourceDefinition"},

    {Group: "flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io", Version: "v1beta2", Kind: "FlowSchema"},
    {Group: "flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io", Version: "v1beta2", Kind: "PriorityLevelConfiguration"},
}

func (c *ErrorInjectingFakeClient) Create(ctx context.Context, obj client.Object, opts ...client.CreateOption) error {
    if c.failError != nil {
        return c.failError
    }

    if err := c.WithWatch.Create(ctx, obj, opts...); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if !c.withSubResourceSimulation {
        return nil
    }

    c.withObjects = append(c.withObjects, obj)
    err := c.recreateFake(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (c *ErrorInjectingFakeClient) Delete(ctx context.Context, obj client.Object, opts ...client.DeleteOption) error {
    if c.failError != nil {
        return c.failError
    }

    if err := c.WithWatch.Delete(ctx, obj, opts...); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (c *ErrorInjectingFakeClient) Update(ctx context.Context, obj client.Object, opts ...client.UpdateOption) error {
    if c.failError != nil {
        return c.failError
    }
    return c.WithWatch.Update(ctx, obj, opts...)
}

// TODO add other K8S client functions you want to inject failures into

func (c *ErrorInjectingFakeClient) SetError(err error) {
    c.failError = err
}

func (c *ErrorInjectingFakeClient) recreateFake(ctx context.Context) error {
    // This is a pretty disgusting hack to get around the fact that the fake client doesn't support creating status subresources
    // Discussed here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/issues/2386#issuecomment-1607768830
    // and here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/issues/2362#issuecomment-1699415588
    // and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489441/go-k8s-controller-runtime-upgrade-fake-client-lacks-functionality

    // We need to collect all the objects from the fake client, and then re-create the fake client with the status subresource for the created object

    gvks := sets.New(inTreeResourcesWithStatus...)
    for _, o := range c.withObjects {
        gvk, err := apiutil.GVKForObject(o, c.Scheme())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        gvks.Insert(gvk)
    }

    var objs []client.Object
    for _, gvk := range gvks.UnsortedList() {
        objList := &unstructured.UnstructuredList{}
        objList.SetGroupVersionKind(schema.GroupVersionKind{Group: gvk.Group, Version: gvk.Version, Kind: gvk.Kind})

        err := c.List(ctx, objList)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        for _, o := range objList.Items {
            objs = append(objs, o.DeepCopy())
        }
    }

    initObjs := sets.New(objs...).UnsortedList()
    c.withObjects = initObjs
    c.withStatusSubresource = initObjs

    c.WithWatch = fake.NewClientBuilder().
        WithScheme(c.Scheme()).
        WithObjects(c.withObjects...).
        WithStatusSubresource(c.withStatusSubresource...).
        Build()
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can fix this by adding a new `WithStatusSubresource` option.
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/commit/0bff6fc8af438727a2a9e5c8a2050fdad25952b4

For instance, you can build the fake client using this line of code :
cl := fake.NewClientBuilder().WithScheme(s).WithRuntimeObjects(objs...).WithStatusSubresource(<sub_resource_to_add>).Build()

Comment: No you can't, please read the contents. The CR is being created by the tested code, with a random name etc., so you can't setup the fake in advance!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).